# R : nesting by `ifelse()`

Tags: r

I have a data from 1st July, 2007 to 5th October, 2014.

I am trying to create a column named `month_index` of the data frame named `dat` which will take increasing integer values as the year and month increases.

I wrote the following R code but it does not seem parsimonious at all.

```
dat$month_index <- with(dat,
                          ifelse(Year == 2007 & Month == 7, 7, 
                                 ifelse(Year == 2007 & Month == 8, 8, 
                                        ifelse(Year == 2007 & Month == 9, 9, 
                                               ifelse (Year == 2007 & Month == 10, 10, 
                                                       ifelse(Year == 2007 & Month == 11, 11,
                                                              ifelse(Year == 2007 & Month == 12, 12,
                                                                     ifelse(Year == 2008 & Month == 1, 13,
                                                                            ifelse(Year == 2008 & Month == 2, 14, 
                                                                                   ifelse(Year == 2008 & Month == 3, 15,
                                                                                          ifelse(Year == 2008 & Month == 4, 16, 17))))))))
```

How can I perform the code in a few lines ?

Comment: Something like `dat$month_index = Month + 12*(Year == 2008)`

Comment: @Frank but I have Year from 2007 to 2014.

Comment: `Month + 12*(Year - 2007)`?

Comment: @Frank It works `dat$month_index <- with(dat,  Month + 12 * (Year - 2007))`. Thank you, thank you, thank you very much. +1000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best-case scenario for avoiding nested `ifelse` is an algebraic solution. Fortunately, that works here:

```
dat$month_index <- with(dat, Month + 12 * (Year - 2007))
```